# Changing post_status in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to programatically change the post status of a post being created from the front end of a website.

The user fills out a form and gets a preview of their post, if they're happy with it, they hit a submit button which should get the ID, and change the post_status to either `publish` or `pending`, depending on whether or not they are a pre-approved user.

The code I have is:

```
if( isset($_POST['publish-event']) ) :

    // check if they have an approved event
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    if( get_field('approved_organiser', 'user_'.$user_id.'') == true ) :
        $approved = true;
    endif;  


    if( $approved == true ) :
        $status = 'publish';
    else :
        $status = 'pending';
    endif;


    // update event based on status
    $update_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'ID' => $_POST['id'],
        'post_status' => $status,
        'edit_date' => true,
        'post_date' => $_POST['post_date']
    );

    var_dump($update_post);
    wp_update_post($update_post);


    $eventCreated = true;

endif; // end if publish
```

However, the event remains a `draft` in WordPress despite the `$update_post` variable var_dumping as saying `pending` in this case.

Any ideas why it isn't changing the post status?

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**[EDIT]**

Removing the date information from the update_post lets it save as `pending`. I've just tried splitting it up so I do the status first, then the date separately, but this set the status to `pending` and didn't change the post date to the selected scheduled time.

Code:

```
$update_status = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'ID' => $_POST['id'],
    'post_status' => $status
);
$statusTest = wp_update_post($update_status);
var_dump($statusTest);


$update_date = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'ID' => $_POST['id'],
    'post_date' => $_POST['post_date']
);
$dateTest = wp_update_post($update_date);
var_dump($dateTest);
```

In both cases the var_dump spits out the ID of the event, instead of `1` though. I'm not sure why.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**[EDIT 2]**

I've just been googling around and apparently someone had success with adding `'post_date_gmt' => $your_post_date` to the array also, this still didn't work for me though.

Comment: wp_update_post has a return value which should be checked to see if the call worked or not. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: Hi, I've tried writing `wp_update_post($update_post, true);` however nothing actually returns, is this correct?

Comment: `$val = wp_update_post( $update_post );` - can you check the value of `$val`? `1` means the update was successful.

Comment: Ah okay, it returns `0`

Comment: So the update was unsuccessful, hence no change in the post's status.

Comment: Reasons could be many but as a first task, try checking the values of `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['post_date']` are right.

Comment: `$_POST['id']` returns the correct ID for the post being updated, and `$_POST['post_date']` returns the expected date. Overall everything seems to be there. I've just noticed if I remove the date information it saves the post as `pending`, if I put them back in it gets saved as a `draft`.

Comment: Try running the date through a function such as `date()` so that it gets formatted properly. For example: `date( $_POST['post_date'] )`

Comment: Just tried this, seems to have no effect. I was making sure I used the correct format for the date before hand and have var_dumped it to make sure it's correct. It's really strange that it wont update the date for some reason!

Comment: `$_POST['post_date']` is obviously the issue here. Are you sure you're formatting it properly? How exactly are you formatting it?

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve this by using `post_date_gmt`, however I had to split the update up into two parts to actually get it to work. I have the following code that now works:

```
$update_post = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'ID' => $_POST['id'],
    'post_status' => $status
);

$statusTest = wp_update_post($update_post);


if( $_POST['post_date'] > date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ) :

    $gmtdate = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['post_date'] );

    $update_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'ID' => $_POST['id'],
        'edit_date' => true,
        'post_date' => $_POST['post_date'],
        'post_date_gmt' => $gmtdate
    );

    $dateTest = wp_update_post($update_post);

endif;
```

I'm not exactly sure why this works, if I move the code from the second `wp_update_post` into the first one, it fails. Formatted like this, it works. Hopefully this helps a few people out as it seems like an issue that keeps cropping up every now and then.